# How to show cache path pdf file in to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, caching, wkwebview

I have download file and saved it into application memory

/Users/MYName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDE3E3-E3E5-444C-B04F-6F8F971F2739/data/Containers/Data/Application/6A7D0012-9ACC-4383-BDBA-A98B89018C8C/Library/Caches/CreatedURLDirectory/sample.pdf

How to load  Caches/MyDictionaryCreated -> sample.pdf on WKWebView.

```
                *if let url = URL(string: url.path) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                        self.webView.load(request)
                        self.webView.isHidden = false
                    }
                }*
```

Above url is my file path...

But I know this is not proper way to load

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a local file into web view you should use `loadFileURL` instead, for example:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToYourFile)
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
```